# custom job status for awx/ansible tower workflows

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

AWX/Ansible Tower has it's own REST API service. From the below url structure i can get information about an in progress or finished workflow job:

```
https://<awx-ip>/api/v2/workflow_jobs/<job-id>/
```

But the "status" field at this url doesn't show the value i desire. If the templates that run in this job didn't get an error during execution, the value always shows a "successful".

So i need a way to show my desired job status by this rest api service. Maybe below field can be edited, but i don't know how:

```
"job_explanation": ""
```

I only need a field to serve a custom status about the ongoing or completed job. For example "partial", "failed", "successful", "ongoing" etc.

How can i edit or add a field during the ongoing job and after it is completed. Is there a way to manipulate the fields on rest api's job stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the Ansible Tower API Reference Guide [Workflow Jobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Workflow_Jobs), by 
[Retriving a Workflow Job](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Workflow_Jobs/Workflow_Jobs_workflow_jobs_read) the `status: (choice)` can have following values

```yaml
new: New
pending: Pending
waiting: Waiting
running: Running
successful: Successful
failed: Failed
error: Error
canceled: Canceled
```

> ... status about the ongoing or completed job

So the status should be already there.

> For example "partial", "failed", "successful", "ongoing" etc.

So it look like the options you are looking for are already there

- ongoing -> running
- partial -> canceled
- failed -> failed
- successful -> successful

```
curl --silent -u "${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/workflow_jobs/${jobID}/ | jq .
```

Resulting into an output of

```json
...
  "launch_type": "relaunch",
  "status": "running",
  "failed": false,
  "started": "2022-02-04T14:28:04.147633Z",
  "finished": null,
  "canceled_on": null,
  "elapsed": 17.367907,
  "job_args": "",
  "job_cwd": "",
  "job_env": {},
  "job_explanation": "",
...
```

and

```json
...
  "launch_type": "relaunch",
  "status": "successful",
  "failed": false,
  "started": "2022-02-04T14:28:04.147633Z",
  "finished": "2022-02-04T14:28:24.156419Z",
  "canceled_on": null,
  "elapsed": 20.009,
  "job_args": "",
  "job_cwd": "",
  "job_env": {},
  "job_explanation": "",
...
```

> Maybe below field can be edited, but i don't know how: `"job_explanation": ""`

According [List Jobs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Jobs/Jobs_jobs_list) the field

> `job_explanation`: A status field to indicate the state of the job if it wasn’t able to run and capture stdout (string)

therefore it should probably not be edited.

> How can I edit or add a field during the ongoing job ...

The REST API is for creating, starting, stopping and so on of jobs, to remote control the Tower application. The values become set by the application, there is no safe option to set them by yourself via the API.

> ... and after it is completed. Is there a way to manipulate the fields on REST API job stats?

It might be possible to to alter the job result directly within in PostgreSQL application database backend.

Also it might be possible for you the change the application [ansible/awx/](https://github.com/ansible/awx/tree/devel/awx) and the behavior of [awx/api/urls/workflow_job.py](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/awx/api/urls/workflow_job.py).